# Vscode's select interpreter does not work on Mac

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have created a virtual environment and when I use select interpreter to use the python interpreter inside that virtual environment, nothing happens and it keeps using my system's python interpreter.

Also I noticed setting.json is not automatically created inside .vscode which might have something to do with this.

Edit: I was able to create a virtualenv inside my project folder using python extension within vscode, I'm just curious why I can't do it the other way as I'm used to organizing my venvs all in a separate location.

Comment: Please elaborate more about your question. What does "nothing happens" mean in this context? If that meant none of your venvs showed up, you need to add them to PATH so VSCode knows where to find them.

Comment: I meant I can go to the folder manually and select the interpreter, but then vscode goes on using the previous one as if nothing happened.

Comment: VSCode is Electron, and the fact that we have different macOS versions, the operating system itself has nothing to do with it, it may have been one of your extensions or just Visual Studio Code failing to recognize the executable if you downloaded the `python3` compiler/`python` compiler from the web instead of using a package manager or installer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using *CodeRunner* to execute the script, which does not use the interpreter selected by `Python: Select Interpreter`. This command belongs to python extension, so please use `Run Python File` to execute the script.

[image]

Whether to use the python version displayed in the lower right corner of the interface

| Extension | Command |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [CodeRunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) | Run Code | NO |
| [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) | Run Python File | YES |

You will see the terminal command showing the currently used interpreter

[image]

You can also check the current interpreter using the following code

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```